# Font Size and Type not applying with CATextLayer

Tags: ios, text, fonts, layer

I am trying to modify the font properties of a text within a layer but it does not happen. Could anyone help out? Please find code below:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self)
{

    // All HypnosisViews start with a clear background color

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setCircleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];


    // Create the new layer object
    boxLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];

    // Give it a size
    [boxLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 85.0)];

    // Give it a location
    [boxLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(160.0, 350.0)];

    // Make half-transparent red the background color for the layer
    UIColor *reddish = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.75];

    // Get CGColor object with the same color values
    CGColorRef cgReddish = [reddish CGColor];
    [boxLayer setBackgroundColor:cgReddish];

    // Make it a sublayer on the view's layer
    [[self layer] addSublayer:boxLayer];

    NSString *text2 = @"You are me.";
    UIFont *font2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:10.0];
    [text2 sizeWithFont:font2];


    [boxLayer setString:text2];

}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To change the font / font size of a CATextLayer, you have to assign values to the "font" and "fontSize" properties of the layer.

Or you have to use an NSAttributedString in which case the values of that string object are used.

The "sizeWithFont" call you use is an NSString addition that does nothing but calculate and return a CSSize with the width and height of the text you give it in the font you give it. As you don't use the returned CGSize in your code, it does absolutely nothing.

Reference in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Perfect - if it's what you were looking for, please mark this as the correct answer so that it's visible to others this has been solved!

Comment: Sure I will but how to do it? I'm new on this site.

Also about CATextLayer: Is there any way to round layer corner? And how would you break lines for a text inside the layer?

Comment: I haven't asked a question yet :-) but I assume there is something like a check mark under the answer that you can click so the answer is validated as the correct one.

Comment: Have you looked at the properties of CALayer? That will show you how to have rounded corners (through the cornerRadius property). If I look at the documentation for CATextLayer I'd say that the "wrapped" property would allow you to specify that the text lines need to be broken when needed.

Comment: Yes I know about "Wrapped" but it determines whether the text is wrapped to fit within the receiver’s bounds. Like it is breaking when it reaches the edge. This is good. I'm also looking forward to break the text whenever I want before it even reaches the edge. I'll keep exploring. But thanks already for your helpful inputs.

Comment: this was my issue. I was literally unable to figure out why the text won't change size and spent couple days trying to figure out. Once i used text layer.fontSize, it worked!! Thanks!